# C++ weird for loop syntax

Tags: c++, for-loop, morse-code

```
std::string decodeMorse(std::string morseCode) {
    // ToDo: Accept dots, dashes and spaces, return human-readable message
    std::string decoded;
    for( auto p : morseCode ) {
      if( p == '.' )
        decoded += MORSE_CODE[ "." ];
      else if( p == '-' )
        decoded += MORSE_CODE[ "-" ];
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

This is a code extract from https://www.codewars.com

Can somebody explain what `for( auto p : morseCode )` means?
Or perhaps re-write this piece of code in more elaborate way?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: That's a range based `for` loop. It's explained in the C++ Language Standard. Consider reading it.

Comment: 6 years since c++11 is in action, time to read a textbook.

Comment: thank you, now that you named it , it is indeed obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It iterates over every element in `morseCode`, starting from the one `begin` refers to and ending with the one before `end`. The value of each iterated element is copied into `p`, whose type is the type of the dereferenced iterator.