# What does the ":" and "ch" mean in this hash table for loop "for ( char ch : key )"?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I know this may not just be for hash tables but an answer with respect to it will help me better understand it:

```cpp
int hash (const string & key, int tableSize) {
    int hashVal = 0;
    for (char ch : key) // ????lost here??? is ch is just any character in the key???
        hashVal += ch;
    return hashVal % tableSize;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? You've not included a programming language tag. You've just posted a single line of out-of-context code.

Comment: Sorry the language is C++

Comment: Please post code no images

Comment: That is a range based for loop in C++.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Your tag edit was good. The rest of it made things worse. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before posting. You should also read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @KenWhite sorry I am trying to get the hang of using this website properly. I will take the tour and read the help center pages.

Comment: duplicates: ['colon' and 'auto' in for loop c++? need some help understanding the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35490236/995714), [C++ weird for loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42657234/995714), [What is “for (x : y)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24946027/995714)

Answer (score 1):

A string is considered to be a collection of characters.

Explanation: For each character in the string `key`, perform the body of the loop.

`ch : key`

- `ch` is the name of a loop variable, it will be assigned one character at a time from the string called key, and the loop body will be executed with that value of `ch` iteratively
- `:` this delimits the loop variable from the string.

See "[Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)" (since C++11)